# Error in NormalizeData.default running DoubletFinder on an integrated seurat object in R

Tags: r, rna-seq, seurat

I'm trying to run DoubletFinder on a seurat object resulting from the integration of various datasets.

The Seurat object has 2 assays: RNA & integrated.

The integrated seurat object have been fully processed:

- Normalization and FindVariableFeature pre-integration
- ScaleData, RunPCA, FindNeighbors, FindClusters, RunUMAP on the integrated object.

The paramSweep_v3() function of DoubletFinder gives the following output:

```
sweep.res.list <- paramSweep_v3(integrated.seu, PCs = 1:38, sct = FALSE)
Loading required package: fields
Loading required package: spam
Loading required package: dotCall64
Loading required package: grid
Spam version 2.5-1 (2019-12-12) is loaded.
Type 'help( Spam)' or 'demo( spam)' for a short introduction 
and overview of this package.
Help for individual functions is also obtained by adding the
suffix '.spam' to the function name, e.g. 'help( chol.spam)'.

Attaching package: ‘spam’

The following object is masked from ‘package:R.utils’:

    cleanup

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    backsolve, forwardsolve

Loading required package: maps
See https://github.com/NCAR/Fields for
 an extensive vignette, other supplements and source code 
[1] "Creating artificial doublets for pN = 5%"
[1] "Creating Seurat object..."
[1] "Normalizing Seurat object..."
Error in NormalizeData.default(object = GetAssayData(object = object,  : 
  trying to get slot "params" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Why does this indicate there are no slots in my Seurat object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DoubletFinder readme clearly states that you shouldn't run it on an aggregated dataset. It will produce false artificial doublets:

[https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder][1]

> Do not apply DoubletFinder to aggregated scRNA-seq data representing
>   multiple distinct samples (e.g., multiple 10X lanes). For example, if
>   you run DoubletFinder on aggregated data representing WT and mutant
>   cell lines sequenced across different 10X lanes, artificial doublets
>   will be generated from WT and mutant cells, which cannot exist in your
>   data. These artificial doublets will skew results. Notably, it is okay
>   to run DoubletFinder on data generated by splitting a single sample
>   across multiple 10X lanes.

I did it by reading in the individual samples, cluster them individually, run DoubletFinder, remove doublets and then run the integration workflow.